# How to use bluetooth discover device with my application UUID in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, ssdp

I'm working on an application, using bluetooth to transfer file. I have a question about bluetooth discovering. **How can i find other devices which already installed my application when bluetooth discovering?** I knew I have to use UUID, and i also knew the BluetoothDevice can give me UUID from other  devices. However, **i don't know how to add my application's UUID into SDP for bluetooth discovering.**

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, when you call the appropriate listen function, pass it the UUID.

On the client side, call startDiscovery() and listen for the discovered devices.  For each device found, get the BluetoothDevice object and call getUUIDs() to get the UUIDs that the remote device implements.  Check for a match with UUID.equals().

Comment: Hello, Gabe. How can i pass the UUID on server side? Use listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord()? Thanks~

Comment: Yes.  Or the insecure version, depending on your needs.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan How to generate Application UUID

Comment: @GabeSechan Hi , having doubt in understanding the concept.Suppose I have wrist band (say of Mi )and I need to connect it from android app then we need to have the uuids known in advance to initiate communication.?

Comment: @dev_ry the uuid of the communication protocol.not of the devices